# Virtual keyboard in my form. Preventing button focus

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create a virtual NumPad in my form. When the user clicks any of the numpad buttons, the corresponding number should be sent to the currently focused TextBox (or any other text control).

Simulating keystrokes aside, how can I prevent the numpad button, which is inside a numpad control, from stealing focus from the already focused TextBox?

I've tried googling and searching SO but didn't find anything that helped me.

Comment: Just return the focus to the "text" control after the numpad event has fired

Comment: Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864904/creating-a-virtual-numpad-stop-form-from-being-activated-focused?rq=1 Duplicate

Comment: @Josefvz What if I don't know which control had focus before the button was pressed?

Comment: Then i would suggest looking at the linked question, that should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in click event of Numpad button.

```
this.ActiveControl = YourTextboxID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
```

Comment: What you forgot to mention is that he needs to create his own button class to accomplish this. This since you cant call the method SetStyles(...) directly on an instance

Comment: SetStyle(...) is a protected method - I assume any developer understands what it means and what to do about it.